# HTTP relay / proxy / mapping server

Tags: http, proxy, relay

I'm trying to set up a simple relay / mapping server locally and feel there has to be some off the shelf solution, but I can't seem to find it.

I'm debugging an application of mine that needs to connect to host_A.  Instead of connecting to host_A I want to configure it to connect to **local_proxy**.  I don't want to use proxying protocols, but instead want to configure it to connect to `http://localhost:80` and then have **local_proxy** connect to `host_A` and have **local_proxy** simply relay all messages back and forth.

I would expect to have to configure **local_proxy** to tell it what server it is supposed to relaying

Then there is 1 particular endpoint I want to be able to intercept and change the return info so I can better debug my application.

I thought I should be able to do this with [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/), but I couldn't figure out how.

At the moment, this doesn't need to support SSL (though that would always be nice).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to build here is known as a [reverse-proxy](/questions/tagged/reverse-proxy). There is a variety of solutions available for that, but you may produce results fastest with [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx), which can not only be configured for [reverse proxy duties](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) but is also sporting some powerfull SSL capabilities. A minimal solution to your problem would look like this:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    # Adjust for expected hostname. Space-separated list of hostnames possible.
    server_name host_a; 

    location / {
        # Forward all incoming requests to host_a
        proxy_pass http://host_a;
    }
}
```